# React Router Dom v6 - redirecting to another route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, navigation, react-router-dom

I am using the following Router config:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/information" element={<Information />} />
  <Route path="*">
    <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

I would like to navigate to home route and Home component every time when I type the route that is not recognized by the router. Since v6, there is no Redirect component, So I am trying to use Navigate.

**Why my configuration is not working?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new syntax/pattern to replicate the `Redirect` is to render the `Navigate` as the route `element`, and specify the `replace` prop.

RRDv5: `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />`

RRDv6: `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />`

Answer (score 2):

But the code sample above causes an infinite loop if you use it in the same way as the component from react-router v5 (that works just fine in this case actually)

`<Redirect from="/foo" to="/foo/bar" />`

like so:

`<Route path="/foo" element={<Navigate replace to="/foo/bar" />} />`

If route `/foo` doesn't exist - there is no page for this route

I don't really know how to deal with it just yet.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32774777)